# Problem by installing the googleanalytics and google2pandas to the anaconda environment

Tags: python, google-analytics, anaconda, junit-jupiter

I cannot download the package googleanalytics and google2pandas to the anaconda environment

I tried `conda install package`

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda install google2pandas Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - google2pandas

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
```

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

I expect that at least one of those packages will be installed

Answer (score 0):

What it's saying is, that the package is not available through Conda. It doesn't seem to be available through Conda Forge either.

I have just installed Google2Pandas through pip:

```
pip install Google2Pandas
```

It's probably the same with the other package.